# Assigning a Tuple or Mystery Structure to a Float

Tags: c++, gcc, tuples, c++17, g++

What is the name for the structure below: `(j,0)`?
Why does this (tuple?) thing evaluate to `0.0f`?
Why is it legal C++17 to assign `(j,0)` to a float?

"00_j0-why.cpp"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl, std::flush, std::ostream;

int main(){
    unsigned long int j = 4;
    float k = (j,0);
    cout << "    j = " << j     << endl;
    cout << "(j,0) = " << (j,0) << endl;
    cout << "    k = " << k     << endl;
}
```

Compile command: `g++ 00_j0-why.cpp -std=gnu++17`
Result:

```
    j = 4
(j,0) = 0
    k = 0
```

I have included a complete working example of what seems to me should be a compiler error.  It should have not compiled.  This is an example of the problem I have been tracking for hours and I am absolutely livid that this is legal code.  I do not even have a name for what `(j,0)` is.

Comment: You seem to have already figured it out: `(j,0) = 0`

Comment: It's called "the comma operator".  It's not a tuple.  The expression evaluates to the last item .  It is legal to assign it to a `float`.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea the comma operator existed outside of argument and initializer lists.